# Does this character lose powers at the end of Wonder Woman 1984?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

Towards the end movie, we find

> Cheetah sitting by the rocks watching the sunset after her fight with Wonder Woman. [image]

Does this scene indicate she has lost all her powers or only the powers obtained during the second half of the movie ?

Comment: This Question and the Answers have the highest ratio of spoiler-tagged text I've seen.  +1 for consideration

Comment: @Criggie - Due to pandemic, I assumed not many people have watched it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It would seem she only lost the apex predator aspect granted when she interacted directly with Lord, since he renounced his wish.  She never renounced her initial wish to be like Diana, so I would say she's still at that power level.

Comment: It seemed somewhat ambiguous to me, possibly deliberately so. But this seems to be the best interpretation of what we do know.

Answer (score 5):

> It’s not clear. We never see Barbara renounce either of her wishes: just her looking human. After she is knocked out by Diana, she next appears in human form at the end of the montage of people saying “I renounce my wish”, but while her lips move, she doesn’t speak aloud. So she may have lost some or all of her powers when Lord renounced his wish.

> However, the film didn’t show wishes being undone en mass after Lord renounced: only individual wishes being undone when each wish’s maker renounced.

> That suggests the wish-granting magic is something independent of Lord and the Dreamstone and they were conduits/containers for it. If it was the magic that granted wishes, not its conduit, wishes would have to be renounced by each wish maker.

Comment: @RichardDickson's answer contradicts your first point. Did you miss something, or did he imagine it?

Comment: I can’t answer your question, as I don’t know what Richard Dickson thinks. But the only people who can give a definitive and factual answer the OP’s question are Patti Jenkins and whoever wrote that scene: everyone else has to interpret what they saw and come to their own conclusions.

Comment: You can read his answer to see what he thinks.

Comment: And you can read my answer, my previous comment and watch the film if you haven’t already to draw your own conclusions. And because it’s an entertaining film.

Comment: I watched but don't remember one way or the other.

Comment: @Barmar That scene is open to interpretation by the viewer. Rewatch it and make up your own mind.

Answer (score 1):

> The "apex predator" aspects that Cheetah gained were the "monkey's paw" twists on other people's wishes that Lord had directed into Cheetah. Logically, those aspects would go away when their original holders renounced, as the power, ferocity, etc. flowed back into their original people. The movie is unclear as to whether Barbara gave up her own initial wish to be like Diana. It seems to imply that she did -- we see her mouthing the words -- but it's never made explicit.

> This is a pretty standard comic book resolution -- it seems to say that the story is totally over with no dangling plot threads, but leaves the door open just enough that a later story can easily say, "No, actually she didn't renounce!" and have Cheetah in there with powers comparable to Wonder Woman.